# Question on my interpretation of logical notation relating to alphabets, theoretical comp sci.

Tags: notation, computer-science

EDIT: I cross-posted this, and couldn't delete this one as it had some answers. There is a good answer at:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53056/46284

$\exists x \in \Sigma^* (t=sx)$

Have I interpreted the above into words correctly?:

"There exists a symbol 'x', which is a member of the set which contains all possible strings of alphabet sigma, where sigma contains string 't', which is a concatenation of string x and string s."

I'm not clear on how/whether t=xs is an alphabet.

(Since this question relates to logical notation, the math stack exchange seemed like not the worst place to ask, (and the theo-sci-comp stack was for researchers); sorry if this is in the wrong place. If anyone knows a better place to ask, please let me know.)

Comment: crosspost with: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53046/question-on-interpreting-logical-notation-relating-to-alphabets-theoretical-co?noredirect=1

Comment: @ClementC., in the future, if you're going to suggest another site, please remind people of the requirement not to cross-post.  You might want to tell them how to migrate (click 'flag' and ask the moderators to migrate it).  Cross-posting is forbidden, so just suggesting another site implies that people should do something that we don't want them to do.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. My bad. Will do in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a $\in$ symbol missing, but otherwise it looks like the definition of a suffix of a word. Here is my interpretation:

**Definition**. Let $t$ be of word of $\Sigma^*$. Then a word $s \in \Sigma^*$ is a *suffix* of $t$ if there exists a word $x \in \Sigma^*$ such that $t = xs$.
(With a logical formula: $\exists x \in \Sigma^* \ t = xs$).

Comment: Thank you for this. The definition I was given included brackets around the t=xs, whereas you have left them out. Does that mean they don't have any significance?

Comment: I think the brackets are used for clarification.